# Consume only specific partition message

Tags: apache-kafka

Here is my kafka message producer:

```
        ProducerRecord producerRecord = new ProducerRecord(topic,  "k1", message);
        producer.send(producerRecord);
```

here is my consumer

```
 TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition(topic, 0);
 consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition0));
    final int minBatchSize = 200;
    List<ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
            buffer.add(record);
            System.out.println(record.key() + "KEY: " + record.value());
```

How is it possible to consume only `topic` message having `k1` as partition key

Comment: With "partition key `k1`" I guess you actually mean "message key `k1`". Kafka does do any select on keys for you. When consuming a partition, you have to consume every message from this partition. Whether you do something with it or just drop it if it does not have the right key is up to you.

Comment: you are saying that while receing messages shall i do `if(msg.key().equals("k1")`

Comment: Yes, thats the way to go.

Comment: can' i define it somehow that i will only consume `topic` message having key `k1`?

Comment: I just notice that my initial comment is missing a crucial **not**. It should have been "Kafka does *not* do any select on keys for you."

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see to implement such behavior is to have the number of partitions == number of possible keys and have a custom partitioner to maintain key uniqueness for a partition (default hash partitioner would work I think). But this solution is very far from optimal and I can't recommend it. Besides that you can't use any built in mechanism to achieve similar behavior - you'll have to filter messages on client side

Comment: don't you think this feature of kafka is not good. e.g. i am posting a message to `topic` and all `topic` subscriber will get message despite of it was not intended to send them cos filtering is supposed to be on client side based on message key

Answer (score 0):

One proposal is to remember the `partition` and `offset` of your specific message, 
and using `assign` and `seek`, `poll` in consumer side.(also set consumer max.poll.records=1, which fetch one message in one time).

- assign, assign specific partition to consumer;
- seek, seek to specific offset, then next poll will get your expected message `K1`.

Note:It works like "random" seek, but will reduce message consumption performance.
0.10 new consumer and new config max.poll.records are required.